# 500 Status in Headers, But Page Loads Fine

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP application using php7.4 fpm and apache2. There's a strange problem where most pages return a status code of 500, meaning internal server error, however the browser loads the page just fine and there are no errors in any apache or PHP logs that I can find. It doesn't make sense to me that the browser would ignore the 500 error... but it does

Since everything appears to work, there really isn't a problem. Except that there are some Ajax calls and other processes that are explicitly checking the status and aborting if it's not 200.

This application is a 3rd party ioncube encoded PHP application, so I can't view the source code. I've asked the original developers to take a look but they couldn't find anything wrong. I have the same application running on a dev machine that's setup pretty similar and it does not have this problem. So I've ruled out the application itself, it's got to be environmental.

I'm at a loss at where to look next, I'm not new at managing a Linux server and apache so I feel frustrated that I can't track this problem down. I've searched google relentlessly, tried swapping PHP versions, checked and double-checked file permissions and ownership. I've been looking for weeks and can't find the problem. I'm sure I'm missing something probably obvious, I just can tell what.

If anybody can give me some ideas as to where I can look next, I'd be grateful.

Screenshot of response headers on a page that otherwise loads fine. This page isn't doing much of anything other than displaying phpinfo() along with the applications menu system:
[Headers Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mScPq.png)

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting turned all the way on?

Comment: Yes, I've set reporting to E_ALL and set it to both log and display errors. Nothing shows up anywhere.

Comment: Have you checked with the developers to see if their code is unsetting those options maybe? Also, the browser isn't ignoring the 500 error, it is totally valid to send that header along with HTML content, just like a 404 page. Browsers just don't bother showing those errors unless you open the developer tools because there isn't really anything a user can do about it.

Comment: I did check with them and yes, they are unsetting them, in order to turn them on I had to add values to a configuration file for the app. I could see test errors I injected but nothing else. About the browser not ignoring, I guess you're right, as long as there's content, it will be displayed. I guess I'm used to seeing the standard error page when there's a problem.